# Dockerized Shiny Appp always shows Hello World not actual app from code while in RStudio its perfect

Tags: r, shiny, dockerfile, rstudio, shinyapps

I have a code of 200 lines in R for shiny app which works perfect when I run from RStudio , while I have to Dockerize the app but when I run docker version of the app , I only see Hello-World app on localhost but not the actual code. I see inside container there are some extra files which docker always copies which is the problem, Can someone help me out ?

this is Dockerfile

```
FROM rocker/shiny:3.5.1
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev libv8-3.14-dev -y &&\
  mkdir -p /var/lib/shiny-server/bookmarks/shiny
# Download and install library
RUN R -e "install.packages(c("library(shiny)","shinydashboard","xlsx", "V8"))"
# copy the app to the image
COPY app /srv/shiny-server/
# make all app files readable (solves issue when dev in Windows, but building in Ubuntu)
RUN chmod -R 755 /srv/shiny-server/
EXPOSE 3838
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server.sh"]
```

Thanks
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could copy additional files / folders individually, e.g.:

```
COPY modules /srv/shiny-server/modules
COPY R /srv/shiny-server/R
COPY *.R /srv/shiny-server/
COPY www /srv/shiny-server/www
```

Not sure, but are you copying your shiny-server.sh file over? I usually run my dockerized Shiny Apps with:

```
CMD ["Rscript", "-e", "shiny::runApp('/srv/shiny-server/', host='0.0.0.0', port=3838)"]
```

Comment: I have only two files in my app , one is App.R and second is excel sheet where data is. Issue is Docker brings extra files , I dont have to bring extra files and secondly I have tried copying my both files one my one also with COPY in Dockerfile. Since I never worked with shiny, Is it compulsory keep some specific file name ? like ui.R , app.R , server.R as I only have one file with code. Regarding my Dockerfile, I took it from [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/2019/02/deploying-an-r-shiny-app-with-docker/). Please let me know if you need more explanation of structure screenshot or code etc.

Comment: All files are in your app folder? I can imagine that you run into working directory problems. I think you app.R file should be in srv/shiny-server/app.R

Comment: proj has only two files which are inside app folder. 1 is excelsheet which contain data. 2nd is App.R having code to visualize the data from excel sheet. App.R has 200 lines which I tried pasting but didn't work, I don't know if can share file in comment. In Dockerfile above I COPY app folder which has only App.R and xlsx file. This app works perfect in RStudio.Issue is that when I run via docker I dont see my app on localhost instead I see HelloWorld app from Shiny. After image is build Inside docker image it has some extra files e.g index.html etc. I simply have to dockerize this app.